Cannot find the option to specify alternative coverage runner under code coverage in Inteliej
im trying to setup jacoco on intelliej. I have went to Run > Edit Configurations but their is no option to specify alternative coverage runner under code coverage.
enter image description here
I followed many tutorials, but all lead to specify alternative coverage runner not showing

At some moment in time this setting has been moved - in IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.2 you can find it in project settings (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-coverage.html#project_settings):

